# As yeast is a fungus, are there any alcohol recipes that contain mushrooms?

Tags: brewing, ingredients, craft-beers, mushrooms, recipes

As fully asked in the question are there any alcohol recipes that contain mushrooms?

Answer (score 2):

**As yeast is a fungus, are there any alcohol recipes that contain mushrooms?**

The short answer is **yes, but you still need the yeast to start the fermentation**.

> **Mushroom-Infused Beer Recipes**
>
> Below you’ll find some basic beer recipes that incorporate mushrooms. Each recipe is sized to make 5 gallons of beer. However, given the broad range of ingredients available to homebrewers, you don’t have to limit yourself to the ingredients you see here. You can modify any existing recipe. Just be sure to formulate your beer to balance sweetness and bitterness. And consider making it a specialty regional beverage that incorporates local and organically grown ingredients. Have fun making your first mushroom beer, and “hopfully” many more!
>
> **Turkey Tail Ale**
>
> A golden pale ale with turkey tail (Trametes versicolor)
>
> - 6 pounds extra-light malted grain
> - 4 ounces fresh or 2 ounces dried turkey tail mushrooms
> - 1 ounce hops
> - Ale yeast
>
> **Iceman Amber**
>
> An amber ale with birch polypore (Piptoporus betulinus) and amadou (Fomes fomentarius)
>
> - 6 pounds extra-light malted grain
> - 1 pound amber malt
> - 12 ounces carrot juice (preferably organic)
> - 4 ounces fresh or 2 ounces dried birch polypore mushrooms
> - 4 ounces fresh or 2 ounces dried amadou mushrooms
> - 1 ounce hops
> - Ale yeast
>
> **Reishi Red**
>
> A natural red lager with reishi (Ganoderma spp.)
>
> - 6 pounds extra light malted grain
> - 1 pound amber malt
> - 12 ounces red beet juice (preferably organic)
> - 4 ounces fresh or 2 ounces dried reishi mushrooms
> - 1 ounce hops
> - Ale yeast
>
> **Agarikon Stout**
>
> A dark, earthy brew with agarikon (Laricifomes officinalis, Fomitopsis officinalis)
>
> - 1 pound chocolate malted grain
> - 1 pound crystal malted grain
> - 5 pounds pale malted grain
> - 2 ounces liquid agarikon mushroom extract (from colonized grain)
> - 1 ounce hops
> - Trappist yeast
>
> Note: Agarikon is endangered and should not be harvested in the wild, but it is a powerful medicinal mushroom worthy of a stout beer. Since this mushroom cannot be cultivated in large quantities and the mycelium is slow to grow, the best option for this recipe is to allow myceliated cakes to supercolonize over the course of several months, until they are thick with biomass, and then prepare an extract from them. - [Brew Outside the Box: Making Mushroom-Infused Beer](https://www.chelseagreen.com/2015/mushroom-infused-beer/)

Technically speaking, working with mushrooms doesn’t pose any major technical hurdles during the brewing process, making it an easy ingredient to play around with, although approaches vary by brewery. Some infuse whole dried mushrooms into the wort (the water extracted during the mashing process), transforming the hot liquid into a sort of mushroom broth, which is then fermented and bottled. Others dry mushrooms and grind them into a powder, which is then made into a tea and added to the beer after fermentation is complete.